# I want mysql table to support two languages

Tags: mysql, jsp, meta

I have a jsp form, there is the next line in the code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I send the parameters of the form into a table in mysql.

the parameters can be in english or hebrew.

I looked if mysql supports the hebrew language:

```
show character set;
```

and got:

```
| hebrew   | ISO 8859-8 Hebrew           | hebrew_general_ci   |      1 |
```

but, when I inserts parameters in hebrew, the fit in mysql shows something like:

```
╫⌐╫?╫?╫?╫?╫?
```

I am trying also to print the parameters in my jsp file and got strange letters..

how can I update my code in order to support english and hebrew?

Comment: is your database explicitly set to be UTF-8?

Comment: I think so, but how can I check that?

Comment: if your using phpmyadmin you can check the 'operations' tab and look for the collation drop down. You should want it to be utf8_unicode_ci.
The same can be checked in the 'structure' tab, looking at individual fields, and checking the collation on those too. If the fields do not show up as utf8 then I believe they all need to be changed manually. Changing just the table properties in the operations in my experience leaves the current fields in their original encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example to create a new table with utf-8 ecoding, this should work for you;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10)
  collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

right after you make a connection. I had the exact same problem with a different language and this fixed it.

Comment: I tried to set:
CREATE DATABASE 'db' CHARACTER SET 'utf8';

and: CREATE TABLE  `Table1` ( [...] ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

but it doesn't work. can you explain what to do again? thank you!