# Php sort with mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to sort names from sql

```
while($ddfg = mysql_fetch_array($result_skey002))
{
    $total = $ddfg['name2'];
}
sort($total);
echo $total;
```

Somthing like that ..,
Im work with name in hebrew so this its doesnt working:

```
$query_skey002 = "SELECT * FROM s_keywords ORDER BY `name2` ASC";
```

I have no idea how to work with php sort function.
Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should do that in the database, you are overwriting your variable (a string) in the loop and feeding a string to an array function.

Comment: `$total = $ddfg['name2'];` should be `$total[] = $ddfg['name2'];` and `echo $total` should be something else

Answer (score 3):

Don't sort in PHP. Your database query is doing that. No need to sort twice. MySQL can sort hebrew text if you use the correct charset/collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

### Update:

Here is a working example of inserting hebrew into a mysql table. I tested it and it definitely works:

```
mysql> create table hebrew_table (my_column varchar(128)) charset=hebrew;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into hebrew_table (my_column) values ('אחד');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from hebrew_table;
+-----------+
| my_column |
+-----------+
| אחד       |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Mysql query dont know to do that with hebrew.

Comment: Look to see if mysql supports a charset/collation that can sort hebrew.

Comment: @Niv_H - it should work in MySQL.  Is the table using the utf8 character set and collation for that column and is your database connection using UTF8 as well for the client connection character set?

Comment: you might be able to cast as `hebrew_general_ci`

Comment: I tried.. sql not suppurt hebrew, when i insert string in hebrew its showing in gibberish

Comment: Instead of UTF8 charset, try hebrew charset.

Comment: Just check this link, may be you get something ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686510/i-want-mysql-table-to-support-two-languages

Comment: @Niv_H How is the data stored in the database, as the original text or are the characters encoded?

Comment: No.. "אחד" in database is "àçã"

Comment: @Niv_H If possible, you should solve the problem at the source (storing in the database in the right way), then you can sort in mysql en you won't need to encode / decode whenever you need something.

Comment: @Niv_H: Inserting hebrew into a mysql table definitely works. I updated my answer with an example of how to do it.

Comment: @Niv_H This is likely due to charset (or lack of) in the `Content-Type` header of your web server's HTTP response. Your Content-Type should be something like `text/html;charset=charset=ISO-8859-8`.

Comment: I did it `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />`

Comment: @Niv_H Change `windows-1255` to `ISO-8859-8` and make sure the `Content-Type` HTTP header matches.

Comment: @Niv_H What does your HTTP `Content-Type` header look like? If you're not setting one, add this line (before any html is output): `header('Content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8');`

Comment: I added the header you gave me and i replaced the charset in meta.. still dont work

Answer (score 0):

Your database query is proper. It will sort result when your SQL query get executed.

You may improve your select SQL query using below one..

```
$query_skey002 = "SELECT * FROM `s_keywords` ORDER BY `name2` ASC";
```

Comment: MySQL has very less support for other languages as well as php5.5 deprecated MYSQL. Try for MySQLi..